# MongoDB Ensure Index not stopping Duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to stop duplicates in my Mongo DB Collection but they are still getting in. I am reading data from twitter and storing it like:

```
var data = {
    user_name: response[i].user.screen_name,
    profile_image: response[i].user.profile_image_url,
    content: {
        text: response[i].text
    },
    id: response[i].id_str,
};
```

and I have the following to stop any duplicates:

```
db[collection].ensureIndex( { id: 1, "content.text": 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } );
```

The id field is working and no duplicates appear but "content.text" field does not work and duplicates are appearing. Any Ideas why?

Comment: Ah, is it possible then to ensure multiple index's on an individual basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enforce a [unique](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-indexes) constraint on a composite index, two documents are considered same only if the documents have the same value for both `id` and `context.text` fields and not for either key individually.

To enforce unique constraints on the fields, `id` and `context.text` individually, You could enforce it as below:

`db.col.ensureIndex({"id":1},{unique:true})` and similarly for the other field.